# Assigning Gnome overview mode to custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

How can I assign Gnome's overview mode to a custom shortcut?

What would be the command that I need to call with my keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Gnome 3.8, you can set a custom keyboard shortcut for the activities overview under Shortcut -> System -> Show the activities overview.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you could go about doing this.

### Replacing <kbd>Super</kbd>:

If you want to *replace* the <kbd>Super</kbd> key you can use dconf editor.

First install dconf with:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then open dconf and navigate to:

```
org -> gnome -> mutter
```

and change the value of `overlay-key` from `Super_L` to whichever key you want to use. (Unfortunately I'm not sure what the strings for all the keys are...).

### Dual overview keys

If you would like to make another key, in *addition* to the <kbd>Super</kbd>, activate the overview you will need `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xdotool
```

Now create the xbindkeys configuration file:

```
touch .xbindkeysrc
```

And edit that file:

```
gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

And add:

```
xdotool key 'Super_L'
customKey
```

Replace `customKey` with the key you want to use to open the overview.

You can find key names with

```
xbindkeys -k
```

(Credit for the [dconf solution](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/10201/bind-gnome-3-overview-mode-to-a-mouse-button/?answer=11779#post-id-11779) goes to user [SoumyaC](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/users/127/soumyac/) on [Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/questions/))